# General solution expressed in $a_0$ and $a_1$ of a Fibonacci-like sequence?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, diophantine-approximation

> What is the general solution expressed in $a_0$ and $a_1$ of a Fibonacci-like sequence ?

I mean if $a_0,a_1$ are given and $a_{n+1}:=a_n+a_{n-1}$

$(\begin{array}{cc}a_n&a_{n-1}\end{array})=(\begin{array}{cc}a_{n-1}&a_{n-2}\end{array})\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\1&0\end{array}\right)=(\begin{array}{cc}a_{1}&a_{0}\end{array})\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\1&0\end{array}\right)^{n-1}$

or according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Use_in_mathematics) formula; $a_n=a_1\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{n-k-1}{k}+a_0\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n-2}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{n-k-2}{k}$

Comment: What's the question? Isn't the formula given at the end the "general solution"?

Comment: (There are other formulations of the "general solution"---are you looking for one of those?)

Comment: @Travis Yes it is an exercise I have to use ''the machinery of the linear recurrence relations'' to get a general solution

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you want to do: Do you want to derive the formula you give for $a_n$? Or produce another formula altogether?

Comment: @Travis I also don't understand the exercise, is the first solution sufficient ? the second has not much to do with the method, I just found it in the internet. but in the first one there's also an annoying term $a_{n-1}$ can one not avoid that ?

Comment: It really depends on the context in which the exercise was given---"the machinery of the linear recurrence relations" is not terribly specific. Of course, you should use whatever techniques you've seen in the course in which the problem was given...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution will be as follows:
$a_n = \dfrac{\varphi_2a_0 - a_1}{\varphi_2 - \varphi_1}\varphi_1^{n} + \dfrac{a_1 - \varphi_1a_0}{\varphi_2 - \varphi_1}\varphi_2^{n}$, where $\varphi_{1,2} = \dfrac{1 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$ -- roots of equation $\varphi^2-\varphi-1 = 0$.  You can check it by substituting this formula to the recurrence.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve the recurrence to get

$$a_n=\frac{(a_0\chi-a_1)\phi^n-(a_0\phi-a_1)\chi^n}{\chi-\phi}$$

Where $\phi$ is the positive solution of $x^2=x+1$ and $\chi$ is the negative.